# Insert data in mongodb with node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, insert

I'm pretty new in node.js and I'm learning by my own, so I'm sorry if I ask stupid/easy questions.

I want to make a register form and insert the data into mongodb. I'm using express and mongoose to do that but I don't know how to insert the data in my database.

Here is what I've got:

My structure is:

```
Project
|--models
   `--user.js
|--routes
   `--api.js
|--www
   `--register.html
|--server.js
   package.json
```

The content is:

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var user = require('./models/user');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Testdb');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));

app.get("/register", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile("register.html", { root: path.join(__dirname, './www')});
});

app.post("/register", function(req, res){
    var u = new user();
    u.firstname = req.body.firstname;
    u.lastname = req.body.lastname;
    u.locality = req.body.locality;
    u.email = req.body.email;
    u.password = req.body.password;
//here I get the parameters correctly but I don't now what to do with the user object to insert it in the database
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('API is running on port 3000');
```

user.js

```
var restful = require('node-restful');
var mongoose = restful.mongoose;
var crypto = require('crypto');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    locality: String,
    email: {type: String, unique: true},
    password: String
});

userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var user = this;
    var shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1');
    shasum.update(user.password);
    user.password = shasum.digest('hex');
    next();
});


module.exports = restful.model('Users', userSchema);
```

api.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var user = require('../models/user');

user.methods(['get', 'put', 'post', 'delete']);
user.register(router, '/users');

module.exports = router;
```

register.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><Document></Document></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/register" method="POST">
        <label>Name</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="firstname"/><br/>
        <label>Surname</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="lastname"/><br/>
        <label>Locality</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="locality"/><br/>
        <label>Email</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="email"/><br/>
        <label>Password</label><br/>
        <input type="password" name="password"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

From postman when I do a POST to http://localhost:3000/api/users it works, but I want to do it when I submit the form and that's what I don't know how to do it. When I submit the form it reminds loading forever waiting to do something... how can I make a post of this data into de database from node.js?

Anyone can help me with this? 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the DAO methods from the route handler and on callback from DAO method, you should send success or failure response to your client side.

For more information, you may look at -

[This article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4)

Hope this will help you

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
db.collection.insert();
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/